# Can't install torch on linux box using pip

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

As the title states I am trying to install torch on linux using pip. 
I run the command `pip install torch==0.3.1`

And I get the following output:

```
Collecting torch==0.3.1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==0.3.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1)
No matching distribution found for torch==0.3.1
```

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try update pip itself, using

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

then,

```
pip install torch==0.3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like this:

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

then,

```
 pip install torch==0.3.1
```

Comment: This is running on an aws box and it doesn't have  "apt-get".
What command should I be using instead ?